# New Measure not visible in Dashboard Designer - SharePoint 2010

Tags: ssas, cube, bids, dashboard-designer, measures

I have created a cube in Sql Server Analysis Service. I have a table called Orders which has several columns in which Quantity, Price and Cost are important. I have already added these fields as Measure in the cube and I can see these Measures in DashBoard Designer.

Later, I added three calculated columns as under.

1. Sales_Amount = Quantity * Price
2. Cost_Amount = Quantity * Cost
3. Profit = Quantity * (Price - Cost)

I was also able to add these new calculated columns as Measures in the cube.
Later I deployed the cube but these new Measures are not visible in Dashboard Designer.

I redployed the cube, deleted connection in Dashboard Designer and readded, created a new workspace but nothing helped and I don't have idea what to do.

Help please.

- Merin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to close the Dashboard Designer and reopen it again? I know it sounds like a lame question but we were facing this problem several times and the solution seemed to be completely closing dashboard designer and reopening it again.

Comment: Thank you very much Omar. That was awesome.